# Processing by controller#action as JS instead as HTML ( I want to process it as HTML )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form to edit a resource and unlike all other posts, I want to process it as HTML and not as JS.

I have no idea why I'm getting `Processing by UserDataController # edit_contact as JS` instead of HTML.

Also I have removed turbolinks, but several other forms that I generated with scaffold that work well (they are being processed as HTML instead of JS), but this custom form that I made is doing the opposite, so I don't know what could this be.

The entire controller is:

```
class UserDataController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def reputation
  end

  def edit_contact
  end

  def update_contact
    if current_user.contact_info.update(contact_params)
      redirect_to user_data_edit_contact_path, notice: 'Se editaron los datos de contacto exitosamente.'
    else
      redirect_to user_data_edit_contact_path, alert: 'Hubieron errores al editar los datos de contacto.'
    end
  end

  def edit_payments
  end

  def update_payments
    if current_user.payment_method.update(payments_params)
      redirect_to user_data_edit_payments_path, notice: 'Se editaron los metodos de pago exitosamente.'
    else
      redirect_to user_data_edit_payments_path, alert: 'Hubieron errores al editar los metodos de pago.'
    end
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contact_params
      params.permit(:name, :last_name, :region, :city, :commune, :email, :cellphone, :whatsapp, :facebook, :telegram)
    end

    def payments_params
      params.permit(:name, :in_person, :paypal, :payoneer, :western_union, :bank_transfer, :check, :cryptos)
    end
end
```

And the view with the form:

```
<%= form_with url: user_data_update_contact_path, method: :post do |form| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h3>Informacón personal</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :name, 'Nombre' %>
        <%= form.text_field :name, value: current_user.contact_info.name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :last_name, 'Apellido' %>
        <%= form.text_field :last_name, value: current_user.contact_info.last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h3>Otros medios de contacto</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :email, 'Correo' %>
        <%= form.text_field :email, value: current_user.contact_info.email, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :cellphone, 'Celular' %>
        <%= form.text_field :cellphone, placeholder: '+569', value: current_user.contact_info.cellphone, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :whatsapp %>
        <%= form.select :whatsapp, options_for_select([['Si', true], ['No', false]], current_user.contact_info.whatsapp), {}, { class: "form-control" } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :facebook, 'Usuario de facebook' %>
        <%= form.text_field :facebook, placeholder: 'Link entero al perfil de facebook', value: current_user.contact_info.facebook, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :telegram, 'Usuario de telegram' %>
        <%= form.text_field :telegram, placeholder: 'Id del usuario', value: current_user.contact_info.telegram, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h3>Localidad</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :region, 'Región' %>
        <%= form.select :region, options_for_select(['', 'Arica y Parinacota', 'Tarapacá', 'Antofagasta', 'Atacama', 'Coquimbo', 'Valparaíso', 'Metropolitana de Santiago', 'Lib. Gral. Bernardo O\'Higgins', 'Maule', 'Biobío', 'La Araucanía', 'Los Ríos', 'Los Lagos', 'Aysén del Gral. C. Ibáñez del Campo', 'Magallanes y Antártica Chilena'], current_user.contact_info.region), {}, { class: "form-control selectpicker", "data-live-search" => "true" } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :commune, 'Comuna' %>
        <%= form.select :commune, options_for_select(['', 'Arica', 'Camarones', 'Putre', 'General Lagos', 'Iquique', 'Alto Hospicio', 'Pozo Almonte', 'Camiña', 'Colchane', 'Huara', 'Pica', 'Antofagasta', 'Mejillones', 'Sierra Gorda', 'Taltal', 'Calama', 'Ollagüe', 'San Pedro de Atacama', 'Tocopilla', 'María Elena', 'Copiapó', 'Caldera', 'Tierra Amarilla', 'Chañaral', 'Diego de Almagro', 'Vallenar', 'Alto del Carmen', 'Freirina', 'Huasco', 'La Serena', 'Coquimbo', 'Andacollo', 'La Higuera', 'Paihuano', 'Vicuña', 'Illapel', 'Canela', 'Los Vilos', 'Salamanca', 'Ovalle', 'Combarbalá', 'Monte Patria', 'Punitaqui', 'Río Hurtado', 'Valparaíso', 'Casablanca', 'Concón', 'Juan Fernández', 'Puchuncaví', 'Quintero', 'Viña del Mar', 'Isla de Pascua', 'Los Andes', 'Calle Larga', 'Rinconada', 'San Esteban', 'La Ligua', 'Cabildo', 'Papudo', 'Petorca', 'Zapallar', 'Quillota', 'La Calera', 'Hijuelas', 'La Cruz', 'Nogales', 'San Antonio', 'Algarrobo', 'Cartagena', 'El Quisco', 'El Tabo', 'Santo Domingo', 'San Felipe', 'Catemu', 'Llaillay', 'Panquehue', 'Putaendo', 'Santa María', 'Quilpué', 'Limache', 'Olmué', 'Villa Alemana', 'Rancagua', 'Codegua', 'Coinco', 'Coltauco', 'Doñihue', 'Graneros', 'Las Cabras', 'Machalí', 'Malloa', 'Mostazal', 'Olivar', 'Peumo', 'Pichidegua', 'Quinta de Tilcoco', 'Rengo', 'Requínoa', 'San Vicente', 'Pichilemu', 'La Estrella', 'Litueche', 'Marchihue', 'Navidad', 'Paredones', 'San Fernando', 'Chépica', 'Chimbarongo', 'Lolol', 'Nancagua', 'Palmilla', 'Peralillo', 'Placilla', 'Pumanque', 'Santa Cruz', 'Talca', 'Constitución', 'Curepto', 'Empedrado', 'Maule', 'Pelarco', 'Pencahue', 'Río Claro', 'San Clemente', 'San Rafael', 'Cauquenes', 'Chanco', 'Pelluhue', 'Curicó', 'Hualañé', 'Licantén', 'Molina', 'Rauco', 'Romeral', 'Sagrada Familia', 'Teno', 'Vichuquén', 'Linares', 'Colbún', 'Longaví', 'Parral', 'Retiro', 'San Javier', 'Villa Alegre', 'Yerbas Buenas', 'Concepción', 'Coronel', 'Chiguayante', 'Florida', 'Hualqui', 'Lota', 'Penco', 'San Pedro de La Paz', 'Santa Juana', 'Talcahuano', 'Tomé', 'Hualpén', 'Lebu', 'Arauco', 'Cañete', 'Contulmo', 'Curanilahue', 'Los Álamos', 'Tirúa', 'Los Ángeles', 'Antuco', 'Cabrero', 'Laja', 'Mulchén', 'Nacimiento', 'Negrete', 'Quilaco', 'Quilleco', 'San Rosendo', 'Santa Bárbara', 'Tucapel', 'Yumbel', 'Alto Biobío', 'Chillán', 'Bulnes', 'Cobquecura', 'Coelemu', 'Coihueco', 'Chillán Viejo', 'El Carmen', 'Ninhue', 'Ñiquén', 'Pemuco', 'Pinto', 'Portezuelo', 'Quillón', 'Quirihue', 'Ránquil', 'San Carlos', 'San Fabián', 'San Ignacio', 'San Nicolás', 'Treguaco', 'Yungay', 'Temuco', 'Carahue', 'Cunco', 'Curarrehue', 'Freire', 'Galvarino', 'Gorbea', 'Lautaro', 'Loncoche', 'Melipeuco', 'Nueva Imperial', 'Padre Las Casas', 'Perquenco', 'Pitrufquén', 'Pucón', 'Saavedra', 'Teodoro Schmidt', 'Toltén', 'Vilcún', 'Villarrica', 'Cholchol', 'Angol', 'Collipulli', 'Curacautín', 'Ercilla', 'Lonquimay', 'Los Sauces', 'Lumaco', 'Purén', 'Renaico', 'Traiguén', 'Victoria', 'Valdivia', 'Corral', 'Lanco', 'Los Lagos', 'Máfil', 'Mariquina', 'Paillaco', 'Panguipulli', 'La Unión', 'Futrono', 'Lago Ranco', 'Río Bueno', 'Puerto Montt', 'Calbuco', 'Cochamó', 'Fresia', 'Frutillar', 'Los Muermos', 'Llanquihue', 'Maullín', 'Puerto Varas', 'Castro', 'Ancud', 'Chonchi', 'Curaco de Vélez', 'Dalcahue', 'Puqueldón', 'Queilén', 'Quellón', 'Quemchi', 'Quinchao', 'Osorno', 'Puerto Octay', 'Purranque', 'Puyehue', 'Río Negro', 'San Juan de la Costa', 'San Pablo', 'Chaitén', 'Futaleufú', 'Hualaihué', 'Palena', 'Coyhaique', 'Lago Verde', 'Aysén', 'Cisnes', 'Guaitecas', 'Cochrane', 'O\'Higgins', 'Tortel', 'Chile Chico', 'Río Ibáñez', 'Punta Arenas', 'Laguna Blanca', 'Río Verde', 'San Gregorio', 'Cabo de Hornos', 'Antártica', 'Porvenir', 'Primavera', 'Timaukel', 'Natales', 'Torres del Paine', 'Santiago', 'Cerrillos', 'Cerro Navia', 'Conchalí', 'El Bosque', 'Estación Central', 'Huechuraba', 'Independencia', 'La Cisterna', 'La Florida', 'La Granja', 'La Pintana', 'La Reina', 'Las Condes', 'Lo Barnechea', 'Lo Espejo', 'Lo Prado', 'Macul', 'Maipú', 'Ñuñoa', 'Pedro Aguirre Cerda', 'Peñalolén', 'Providencia', 'Pudahuel', 'Quilicura', 'Quinta Normal', 'Recoleta', 'Renca', 'San Joaquín', 'San Miguel', 'San Ramón', 'Vitacura', 'Puente Alto', 'Pirque', 'San José de Maipo', 'Colina', 'Lampa', 'Til Til', 'San Bernardo', 'Buin', 'Calera de Tango', 'Paine', 'Melipilla', 'Alhué', 'Curacaví', 'María Pinto', 'San Pedro', 'Talagante', 'El Monte', 'Isla de Maipo', 'Padre Hurtado', 'Peñaflor'], current_user.contact_info.commune), {}, { class: "form-control selectpicker", "data-live-search" => "true" } %>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit "Guardar" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please, change "Hubieron errores" for "Hubo errores" .

Comment: @Pablo mmmmm, no :D

Comment: OK. If you like grammatical errors, its your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form_with` helper has `remote: true` option by default in Rails 5. You need to add `local: true` to change it's behaviour to working through html

Comment: According to the docs, you must use `local: true` to disable the remote option. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with